# How do classifiers classify?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, classification

After training any classifier, the classifier tells the probability of data point belonging to a class.

`y_pred = clf.predict_proba(test_point)`

Does the classifier predicts the class with the max probability or does it considers the probabilities as a distribution draws according to distribution?

In other words, suppose the output probability is -

```
C1 - 0.1      C2 - 0.2      C3 - 0.7
```

Will the output be C3 always or only 70% of the times?

Comment: it's hard to answer this question as every classifier works differently (some don't have the predict_proba method) but in a general way your classifier will always answer C3. However it warns you that in your training, the distribution of class is like this on the surrounding of the sample (close space). But the surrounding is really not well defined and again depends on the classifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to go from class probability scores to a class is often called the 'decision function', and is often considered separate from the classifier itself. In scikit-learn, many estimators have a default decision function accessible via `predict()` for multi-class problems this generally just returns the largest value (argmax function).

However this may be extended in various ways, depending on needs. For instance if the effects of one prediction one of the classes is very costly, then one might weight those probabilities down (class weighting). Or one can have a decision function that only gives a class as output if the confidence is high, else returns an error or a fallback class.

One can also have multi-label classification, there the output is not a single class but a list of classes. `[ 0.6, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2 ]` -> `(class0, class2)` These can then use a common threshold, or a per-class threshold. This is common in tagging problems.

But in almost all cases the decision function is a deterministic function, not a probabilistic one.

Answer (score 1):

When clf predict it won’t calculate the probably of each class . It will use the full connect get a array like [itemsnum ,classisnum] then you can use max output[1] get the items class
by the way when clf training it use softmax to get the probably of each class which is more smooth to optimize you can find some doc about **softmax** if you are interested about train process